# Arduino memory issues when using multiple multiplexers

Tags: c++, arduino

I am working on an arduino project and I need a lot of in- and outputs. The current setup has 5 multiplexers each having 3 rows of 16 bits. The problem is that the default library only supports one multiplexer. I think this is because the `_shiftReg` variables used in the library are shared across all 5 multiplexers instead of applying to only one.

I tried modifying the the library to support multiple multiplexers by adding the `_shiftReg` variables to the header file of the library. This solved the problem, but it is also where a new one arises.

There are toggles controlling almost all in- and outputs. I pass each toggle the multiplexer of the in- and output it has to control. This however causes massively increased memory usage for each toggle I add. I think it's because the multiplexer objects are being copied instead of passed just as a reference. I'm used to writing Java and I don't know how C++ handles these things. Do I need to change the way I pass the variables to not use so much memory? Or is it something else causing these problems?

It wouldn't be very readable if I pasted all the code here, so I made a [GitHub repo](https://github.com/jochim-van-dijck/Arduino) to make it easier to view.

Answer (score 1):

The objects are being passed by reference, however the library does make copies of them.

You could change:

```
MuxShield _muxShieldIn;
MuxShield _muxShieldOut;
```

To references:

```
MuxShield &_muxShieldIn;
MuxShield &_muxShieldOut;
```

However the constructor will need to be modified so it uses an initializer list.

At the moment, it does a copy here:

```
ToggleMux::ToggleMux(MuxShield & muxShieldIn, int inRow, int inBit, MuxShield & muxShieldOut, int outRow, int outBit)
{
    _muxShieldIn = muxShieldIn;
    _muxShieldOut = muxShieldOut;
//...
```

You'll need to change it look like this:

```
ToggleMux::ToggleMux(MuxShield & muxShieldIn, int inRow, int inBit, MuxShield & muxShieldOut, int outRow, int outBit) : _muxShieldIn(muxShieldIn), _muxShieldOut(muxShieldOut)
{
//...
```

---

Also the arrays in the `MuxShield` class `_shiftReg1`, `_shiftReg2` and `_shiftReg3` can be chars, as they only store a 1 or 0, this will halve their usage.

Or you could use my BitBool library (download from library manager) to make each one take only two bytes. All you'd need to do (after including it to your sketch and lib) is:

Change the declarations to:

```
BitBool<16> _shiftReg1, _shiftReg2 _shiftReg3;
```

And the initializations to:

```
BitBool<16> _shiftReg1 = {0};
BitBool<16> _shiftReg2 = {0};
BitBool<16> _shiftReg3 = {0};
```

Then all three variables take 6 bytes instead of 96. My class is designed to be used like an array, so you shouldn't need to change any other code.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. Your solution works great, however I think the shiftReg arrays are still being shared between the muxshield objects. Do you think this is possible?

Comment: Only if they are static, which they aren't, so each instance of MuxShield gets their own set. In the morning I'll have a further look at what may be happening.